# What is the << operator for in C++?

Tags: c++, function, operators

I come from a C# and Java background into C++ and I'm trying to get to understand the `>>` & `<<` operators such as in

```
std::cout << "Hello World";
```

What I can't understand in here is what the `<<` operator is for. I tried declaring my own simple function that always returns the integer `5` and I can call it as I did in C#,

```
int x = MyFunction();
```

and that turns `x` into `5`, but why do I need to use `std::cout` with `<<`? Also I would really appreciate it if you helped me understand what both `>>` and `<<` are for.

Thanks to all of you for helping me understand this. What actually opened my mind is the fact that std::cout is and object :)

Comment: `<<` is used for both shifts and streams.

Comment: Using these for input and output is one of the first things you do in any book or tutorial on C++. Look into those.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't spell it out exactly, but I believe that your confusion is that you think that `std::cout` is a function, and you're wondering why you don't just call it like this:

```
std::cout("Hello World");
```

Well, `std::cout` is not a function.  The function in this statement is `operator<<`.

```
std::cout << "Hello World";
```

Or, more specifically, the function is `std::ostream::operator<<(const char*)`.

The thing you need to understand is that operators are just functions with an alternative calling syntax.  `operator<<` is overloaded as a member function of `std::ostream`, and `std::cout` is an object of `std::ostream`.  So this:

```
std::cout << "Hello World";
```

Is an alternative way to call this:

```
std::cout.operator<<("Hello World");
```

Note that `operator<<` is a binary operator, which means it takes two arguments, if it's declared as a free function, and one argument if it is declared as a member function.  When you use the alternative calling syntax, the object on the left is the first argument, and the object on the right is the second argument.  In the case where it is declared as a member function, as it is in this case, the object on the left is the calling object, and the object on the right is the argument.

Here's what it would look like if it were declared as a free function:

```
operator<<(std::cout, "Hello World");
```

But, whether it is declared as a member or a free function, you can still use the same alternative calling syntax.

Comment: "operator<< is overloaded as a member function of std::ostream" -- as it happens the `(std::ostream, const char*)` overload of `operator<<` called by this code is a non-member function. Not that it makes much difference.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that a bit too late.  Then I worried that the surgery required to fix that discrepancy would confuse the OP.  Pandiux, if you're reading this, replace "Hello World" with the number 10, and `const char*` with `int`, and it should be correct.

Comment: +1 as the only one who noted the misleading interpretation of cout as a function (like write or similar) instead of as an object

Answer (score 2):

In the case of I/O streams the `<<` and `>>` operators are overloaded to mean something other than bit shifting.  For example, [std::ostream::operator<<](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) is overloaded for many types, and you can add overloads for your own types as well.  For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class my_type {
public:
    my_type(const std::string &name) : _name(name) { }
    const std::string &get_name() const { return _name; }
private:
    std::string _name;
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const my_type &foo ) {
    return out << foo.get_name();
}

int main() {
    my_type m("foo");
    std::cout << m;   // prints "foo"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 only one which notes that `>>`/`<<` are overloaded and the behavior depends on that.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what they do. This doesn't look very helpful.

Comment: @CrazyCasta: "Not helpful"?  I was working on a small example, but I think differentiating between the shift operators and their overloaded brethren, as well as providing a link to all of the overloads for `std::ostream`, is helpful.

Comment: "to mean something other than bit shifting"? Why not just say used for reading/writing streams?

Comment: @CrazyCasta: Because that would be overly specific.  Sure that''s the most common use, but I think it's more important to convey that they are simply overloaded functions which could be implemented for any type and any purpose.  One could add an `operator<< (std::vector<T>& v, const T& obj)` for `std::vector` as well, which has nothing to do with streams.  Best not to make it seem like some special case for these magical "stream" objects.

Comment: @CrazyCasta: Thanks for catching `operator==` :D

Comment: Yeah, I think that was part of my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

`<<` is the left-shift operator, and `>>` is the right-shift operator, just as they are in Java and C#.

However, *additionally*, `<<` is overloaded to provide a way of outputting values to a stream. The stream `std::cout` usually refers to the terminal the program was launched in, and writing something to that stream with `<<` will write it to the terminal. `>>` is similarly overloaded to read from streams, and in the case of the stream `std::cin` to read from the terminal the program was launched on.

This kind of thing works in C++ because you define the behaviour of operators for user-defined types. In java, operators operate only on built-in types - writing `a + b` is an error if `a` and `b` are instances of your own class. In C++, this is allowed *if* the class defines a suitable operator `+`.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++ the << operator means "shift left". In C++, when using the standard template library, the << and >> operators are overloaded to implement a streaming API.

The object std::cout does overload the << operator to use it as a conversion function (in this case to a string printed to the console).

Actually this:

```
int x = myFunction();
std::cout << x;
```

and this:

```
std::cout << myFunction();
```

are functionally the same (besides the definition of the temporary variable x).

Answer (score 1):

In general the `<<` and `>>` operators have the same meaning. However, in the cases that you have given they are stream write and read operators respectively. Specifically, `<<` is the write operator (think of it as pointing towards the stream) and `>>` is the read operator (pointing away from the stream).

They are handled by overloading the `<<` and `>>` operators. In particular, the C++ paradigm is to add overloads for `<<` and `>>` for `ostream`s and `istream`s respectively to handle input and output. C++ does not have a built-in paradigm of `ToString()` the way Java and C# do.

Finally, `std::cout`, `std::cin` and `std::cerr` are instances of `ostream`, `istream` and `ostream` respectively, which is why they get the `<<` and `>>` overloads.

For instance, the following code outputs `Hello World` to the standard output stream.

```
std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
```

Finally, std::endl is a special `ostream` that adds a newline and flush the stream.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, c++ has streams 
<< is an operator that is an operator that is used to "append data" to a stream 
And >> is used to extract data from a stream. 
Of course, you can implement this with classes which are not just streams.