# How can I include .a libraries in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, static, libraries

so I've been trying to include the Bullet physics library to my project and Cmake generated an Xcode project for me which built to static libraries or .a files. All the demos work perfectly from within that project, but I need to be able to use them in my project in C++ Xcode, I've already included the necessary headers, but how do I use the .a files in Xcode 4? Or what else should I do?

Comment: @AdrianCornish I have looked into his questions and most of the answers are acceptable.

Comment: @MarkGarcia How so. The OP asked 6 questions 2 of which have been answered.

Comment: @AdrianCornish At the least he could accept on of those answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772076/what-is-the-operator-for-in-c

Comment: My mistake - 10 questions with 5 answered

Comment: Acceptance of past answers should not be a criteria of how this site works - no matter how many points you wish to earn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the .a files to the project in the same way that you add source files or frameworks, i.e. drag them to the project window or use `Files` => `Add Files to "foo"...`.